# koa-static on Heroku is refusing to serve static files

Tags: node.js, heroku, koa

```
var app = require(koa)();
var serve = require('koa-static');

app.use(serve(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This returns 404s on Heroku, but works perfectly fine on localhost.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Maybe try debugging with `console.log(__dirname)` and make sure that the `public` folder is in the right place

Comment: `serve('public')` works for me (including on heroku). the static middleware resolves the full path for you relative to the top level.

Comment: I had the same problem and I later realized that the folder with the assets was not in source control. In case the public folder is a product of your build process, make sure that it gets called correctly and succeeds (using the postinstall hook in package.json). In the worst case you can always `heroku run /bin/bash` to your app and inspect the files on the CLI